# ionic Bluetooth scan dosen't return any thing

Tags: cordova, bluetooth, ionic2

i try to connect bluetooth via Bluetooth Serial plugin so i write these codes :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BluetoothSerial } from '@ionic-native/bluetooth-serial';


 @Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
 })
  export class HomePage {
    device: Array<any>;
     isconnected: string;
   scanning:string;
     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,public bls:BluetoothSerial) {
    this.device = [];
     this.scanning = "no scan";
    }
   scan(){ this.scanning = "scan";
   let that = this;
   this.bls.list().then(function(d){

    that.device = d;
    that.scanning ="success";
  },function(e){
    that.scanning = "error";
  });
 }
 checkConnect() {
let that = this;
this.bls.isEnabled().then(function(){
  that.isconnected = "Enable";
},function(){
  that.isconnected = "Disable"
})
 }

  }
```

if i run these code in real device or in genymotion emulator with api level 17 and android 4.2.2 i get these errors :
[image]

and if i run this code on device with api 25 and android 7 i can see my app but it dosent scan bluetooth devices ? any one know what is the problem

and this is my ionic info :

`
ionic info

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.4.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.11.0
OS         : Windows 10
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 4.6.1
```

`

Comment: Emulator wont work as it does not have Bluetooth. You need to use a physical device. Does your `checkConnect()` work?

Comment: @Huiting in physical device checkConnect work in API 25 but dosent work in API 17 , acctually in API 17 i only see blank page